# TypeError on np.where using an appended list

Tags: python, numpy, append, where-clause, typeerror

I understand this is a basic question and will probably have been answered before but I cannot find an exact solution after looking for a wee while so would like to ask.

I am making a loop that converts time elapsed to a sine wave and then plots it. I have no problem with this part but I'm struggling with a small bit of analysis after.

```
import time
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []

start = time.time()

for times in range(100):

    stop = time.time()
    duration = stop-start
    x.append(duration)
    y.append(np.sin(duration))

    time.sleep(0.05)
```

This all works fine and produces a graph as required, however I then am looking to use the `np.where` command and it returns an error:

```
print(y[np.where(y > 0)])
```

> TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()

What confuses me is what `time.time()` returns a value as that I then append on to the matrix, if I call `type(y[0])` it gives a `numpy.float` definition. I understand I must just be calling some function wrong or doing something wrong with my list definition! As if I do the same with a simple `int` matrix it all works fine.

```
a = np.arange(0,100,2)
print(a[np.where(a > 80)])
```

> [82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98]

Which is all fine, so I'm just wondering where I've gone wrong on my list definitions for the `TypeError`.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Did you try casting your `x` list to a `numpy` array using `np.array(x)`? Does it produce the same error?

Comment: That does fix it, thank you a lot. Could you explain to me what that changes and how it allows the function to work? Cheers.

Comment: Numpy overrides basic operators for equality, comparison, etc. In this case calling the `>` operator is same as calling [numpy.greater](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Casting `y` into a numpy array `y = np.array(y)` and then use `np.where(y[np.where(y > 0)])` should get you the results you're looking for.

Comment: That works a treat, thanks a lot. Any chance you could explain what it changes to facilitate it? Cheers.

Comment: According to the documentation ( [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) ) `np.where()` requires a array_like condition and does not accept lists.

Comment: @Wrothschild, actually the problem isn't with `where`.  It's with `alist>0`. (Plain) python cannot compare a list with a scalar.  `[i>0 for i in alist]` will probably work.  `anarray>0` works because `numpy` has implemented a element by element comparison.

Comment: I see the difference now, thanks for clearing it up.